# Nginx 500 internal error

Tags: nginx

```
   http {
 server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        server_name node.ramblr.io;
        server_tokens off;
        root /home/john/public_html/node.ramblr.io;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;   

            ssl                  on;
            ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/node.ramblr.io.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/node.ramblr.io.key;
            ssl_session_timeout  5m;
            ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
            ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

                   location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }

                 location ~ /\.ht {
                   deny all;
                    }
    }
}
```

Its in the nginx.conf

that is my nginx config, i have two other sites that are reversed proxied and about only work for index.php for some reason. But want i would like to know is why i am getting 500 internal error off this.

Here is some of my error logs for nginx

```
2016/01/16 00:32:36 [crit] 6458#0: *5 stat() "/home/john/public_html/node.ramblr.io//index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 77.98.3.250, server: node.ramblr.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "node.ramblr.io"
2016/01/16 00:32:36 [crit] 6458#0: *5 stat() "/home/john/public_html/node.ramblr.io//index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 77.98.3.250, server: node.ramblr.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "node.ramblr.io"
2016/01/16 00:32:36 [error] 6458#0: *5 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "//index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html", client: 77.98.3.250, server: node.ramblr.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "node.ramblr.io"
2016/01/16 00:32:48 [crit] 6458#0: *6 stat() "/home/john/public_html/ramblr.io/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 77.98.3.250, server: ramblr.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "test.animegrinder.com"
2016/01/16 00:32:48 [crit] 6458#0: *6 stat() "/home/john/public_html/ramblr.io/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 77.98.3.250, server: ramblr.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "test.animegrinder.com"
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /home/john/public_html/ramblr.io` ? It looks like Nginx worker doesn't have permissions to read this directory

Comment: To avoid internal redirection you can try to add an empty location: `location ~ \.html$ { }`

Comment: location ~ \.html$ {
  }
Worked if i wanted to use like .php files i would need to add another like like this?   location ~ \.php$ { }

Comment: [root@webserver public_html]# ls -l /home/john/public_html/node.ramblr.io
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 0 Jan 15 20:37 index.html

Comment: Would like to add this is nginx 1.8.0 compiled from source

Comment: If you want `.php`, your `location` must not be empty, otherwise all of the file contents (including PHP code) will be shown to the user. You should use `proxy_pass` and some other directives, as well described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-debian-7)